# test pattern matching in haskell

Tags: haskell, testing, pattern-matching

The famous "Learn You Haskell For Greater Good" book contains example of command-line arguments parsing:

```
dispatch :: String -> [String] -> IO ()
dispatch "add" = add
dispatch "view" = view
dispatch "remove" = remove
main = do
   (command:argList) <- getArgs
   dispatch command argList
```

Until pattern-matching is straightforward, there is no point in testing it, but things quickly become more complex:

```
main :: IO()
main = getArgs >>= dispatch

dispatch :: [String] -> IO()
dispatch ("add":args) = add args >> list
dispatch ("remove":args) = remove args >> list
dispatch ("view":[]) = list
dispatch [] = list
dispatch _ = usage
```

Now idea appears to test if every particular input sample triggers correct pattern-match branch. If dispatch had anything to return, it was no problem, but it doesn't unfortunately.
My thoughts are:

1. I feel dispatch should return "action", but matching once again by action seems stupid :)
2. May be pattern-matching is misused here, though it looks like good test case.
3. May be code **must** be refactored to make dispatch return something, and this is the only way
4. Something else

I'd like to have a hint, what assumptions are correct and what are not.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't understand what's you problem is ;（

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read on, LYAH offers some ideas to help improve the robustness of this program --- particularly using the `Maybe` monad and `lookup`.

In regards to your numbered list:

1. Dispatch can return `Action ()` if you define your own type, but `add`, `view` etc must also return `Action ()`.
2. I think pattern matching is a good fit for the task. An improvement of the readability of this `dispatch` could be achieved by using the `PatternSynonyms` language extension, available in GHC as of 20th Jan 2014: https://github.com/ghc/ghc/commit/4f8369bf47d27b11415db251e816ef1a2e1eb3d8
3. As in point **1.**, you must respect the return types of `add`, `view` etc
4. Who knows! You go further and test possible inputs using [QuickCheck](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~rjmh/QuickCheck/manual.html) by defining an `instance Arbitrary Input` but testing *all* possible inputs for `getLine` might take you a while... **:-P**

I hope this has helped

Comment: With the first one I think he meant that `dispatch` should simple returned the parsed `Action` (like `Add args`, `Remove args`, ...) which is later passed to some other function (`execute` for example`) that will execute the parse actions. Essentially splitting `[String] -> IO ()` in: `[String] -> Action` and `Action -> IO ()`.

Comment: Thank you, it looks like the answer i was looking for